# react redux UI not updating after store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Im relatively new to React and Redux, and I created a simple ajax Email form for learning. The issue i'm having is that after form submission I set the store state back to Initialstate, which should clear all fields but it doesn't. I can see the store changes in redux logger, *see image attached but these changes are not showing on the ui. Is my store not mapping to state correctly? Or am I mutating state somewhere?

My reducer looks like the following:

```
export default function contactForm(state = initialState.formValues, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FORM_RESET:
      return initialState.formValues;
    case types.FORM_SUBMIT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, action.message);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Combine Reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import message from './formReducer';
import ajaxCallsInProgress from './ajaxStatusReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  message,
  ajaxCallsInProgress
});
```

My initialstate looks like:

```
export default {
  formValues: {
    name: '', email: '', message: '',
  },
  ajaxCallsInProgress: 0,
};
```

My Actions Look like this:

```
export function messageSuccess(message) {
  return { type: types.FORM_SUBMIT_SUCCESS, message };
}

export function resetForm() {
  return { type: types.FORM_RESET };
}

export function saveMessage(message) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    return messageApi.saveMessage(message)
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(messageSuccess(message));
      dispatch(resetForm());
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(ajaxCallError(error));
      throw (error);
    });
  }
}
```

In the view I am mapping state to props via:

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {
   message: Object.assign({}, this.props.message),
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <ContactForm
      onChange={this.updateMessageState}
      onSubmit={this.submitForm}
      message={this.state.message}
    />
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   message: state.message,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(formActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactSection);
```

Log showing store changes

[image]

I would be very grateful to any advice.

Comment: Can you provide what your initial state looks like?  I think the source of the issue is that you're mutating the state in your reducer.

Comment: Tom, ive just added initialstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following which updated the state. I'm not sure if this is best practise with Redux, but it worked

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ message: nextProps.mail });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've updated my answer with the code that I think should work for your example.  You were pretty close, however based on your comments on trying to combine two reducers, I've created two reducers so you can see how it works.

```
/* constants.js */
export default {
  FORM_RESET: 'FORM_RESET',
  FORM_SUBMIT: 'FORM_SUBMIT',
  AJAX_REQUEST: 'AJAX_REQUEST'
};


/* form-values-reducer.js */
const initialState = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  message: ''
};

export default const formValuesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.FORM_SUBMIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        message: action.message
      };

    case Constants.FORM_RESET:
      return {
        ..state,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

/* ajax-request-reducer.js */
const initialState = {
  ajaxRequestCount: 0
};

export default const ajaxRequestReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.AJAX_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        ajaxRequestCount: state.ajaxRequestCount + 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

/* action-creators.js */
export const resettedForm = () => {
  return {
    type: Constants.FORM_RESET
  }
};

export const submittedForm = (message) => {
  return {
    type: Constants.FORM_SUBMIT,
    message
  }
};

export const ajaxRequested = () => {
  return {
    type: Constants.AJAX_REQUEST
  }
};

/* actions */
export const resetForm = (dispatch) => {
  return () => {
    dispatch(resettedForm());
  }
};

export const submitForm = (dispatch) => {
  return (message) => {
    dispatch(ajaxRequested());
    dispatch(submittedForm(message));
  }
};

/* reducers.js */
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ajaxRequest from './ajax-request-reducer';
import formValues from './form-values-reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  ajaxRequest,
  formValues
});

/* Component */
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { resetForm, submitForm } from './actions';

const App = (props) => (
  <div>Your app UI stuff goes here</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    name: state.formValues.name,
    email: state.formValues.email,
    message: state.formValues.message,
    ajaxRequestCount: state.ajaxRequest.ajaxRequestCount
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    resetForm: resetForm(dispatch),
    submitForm: submitForm(dispatch)
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I've not run this through anything, so there may be some mistakes in the code here and there.

Comment: I am still unable to solve this issue, has anyone else got come across this issue?

Comment: Just had a quick look over your code again, on your `mapStateToProps` method, you're setting `state.message`, but shouldn't it be `state.formValues.message`?

Comment: Thanks Tom, I use initialstate.formvalues, and that returns the message object. It should be state.message because of the combine reducers. I just added my combined reducers.

Comment: @GraemePaul I've updated my answer with code that I think should make your example work.  The UI component logic isn't there, but the redux logic should be fine.

Comment: Thanks again @Tom, Ive changed my reducer but as i pass the message object to the conform component, i would have to split it up. I just created a repo as it may be easier seeing it. https://github.com/graemec23/react-contact-form

Comment: Your `FORM_SUBMIT_SUCCESS` type on your `formReducer` is wrong - you're trying to return just string, but it should be returning an object, with a message property on it.  The bit you've commented out is correct.

Comment: Ive been testing it again, ...state, message: action.message, creates a structure like message > message > name. action.message is an object.

Comment: So does `action.message` look like `{ name: string, email: string, message: string }`?